# Consequtive Cloning via Clone proxy of the OpenZeppelin

Tags: openzeppelin, proxy-contracts, factory, clone

I have used the Clone proxy of the OpenZeppelin in my smart contract letting it somehow duplicate itself whenever running the clone function.

However, by clicking my clone function I am given the returned cloned contract address, but when I navigate to the created contract and execute the clone function again for creating the second one in a row, it does not do and return anything.

It seems Clone proxy only supports one-time cloning and generated contracts ( products of cloning ) cannot execute clone function themselves.

I would be thankful if anyone who knows about it helps me with this issue

Finally, it is worth mentioning that my purpose is to create a smart contract that can copy itself anytime. Then similarly, the generated smart contract should have the ability to copy itself whenever I want.

Thankssssss

( Within this code, fetch() is a function that gives the information of the previous contract to the new generated contract )

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol";


contract BondingCurve is ERC20 {


address payable public owner;

address[] public clones;

// ========================================
// Cloning a contract that will produce a duplicate

function cloneContract() external returns (address) {
    address child = Clones.clone(address(this));
    BondingCurve(child).fetch(tokenHolders, address(this));
    clones.push(child);
    return child;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the code?

Comment: I did bro!! Do u mean there might be something wrong within the cloneContract() function?